# Not able to launch file after makefile in SSH

Tags: ubuntu, github, gcc, ssh, nvidia

So basically, I bought a Ubuntu server, and installed `cuda` on it.

I have installed [github.com/brichard19/BitCrack](https://github.com/brichard19/BitCrack)
and i successfully managed to build the file, `makefile` it.

After all these steps, how can I launch the file? I actually have no idea how to launch it? I am not getting it.

Comment: ./BitCrack -u 1Pzxbxz9Lfcgd3cJZ4XsEraARE1FhVbCCe
-bash: ./BitCrack: Is a directory 

do i run in like this? I am getting this error? I am so sorry for such questions, i have no idea what i am doing haha

Comment: somehow this also pops up! [Error] Error detecting devices: unknown error

Answer (score 0):

The [README mentions](https://github.com/brichard19/BitCrack):

> Use cuBitCrack.exe for CUDA devices and clBitCrack.exe for OpenCL devices.

In your case, look for, after compilation with `make BUILD_CUDA=1`, an executable named `cuBitCrack`

```
cd BitCrack
make BUILD_CUDA=1
./cuBitCrack -u 1Pzxbxz9Lfcgd3cJZ4XsEraARE1FhVbCCe
```